# How can I make a .map?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a little drawback, this is my code:

```
 const overflow = timelineitems && timelineitems[0][Object.keys(datos)[80]].total_cases;
```

at number 80 is the position of a date

```
Object.keys(datos)[80]
```

If I change the number 80 all ok, the date is changed.

Now my problem is that I want to try to make a .map of all the (total_cases) that I have in the array: [link of the api that I am using](https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTimeline=US) I am using timelineitems

trying to make several .map without success, my last attempt was:

```js
const datos = timelineitems && timelineitems[0]

const dateTotalCase = datos[Object.keys(datos)[0]].total_cases,

const dateTotalCase =  datos[Object.keys(datos)[6]].total_cases,

const dateTotalCase =  datos.map((item) => item[Object.keys(item)[1]].total_cases)
```

Everything works, but it just brings me a matrix, and what I want is for you to bring me all the total_case [API LINK](https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTimeline=US)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to extract all the `datos` fields values.

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) returns an Array so you can easily apply `.map()` on it to achieve your initial goal:

```
Object.values(datos).map(item => item.total_cases)
```

---

The complete runnable example with shortened version of data from API:

```js
const data = {
  "countrytimelinedata": [{
    "info": {
      "ourid": 167,
      "title": "USA",
      "code": "US",
      "source": "https://thevirustracker.com/usa-coronavirus-information-us"
    }
  }],
  "timelineitems": [{
    "1/22/20": {
      "new_daily_cases": 1,
      "new_daily_deaths": 0,
      "total_cases": 1,
      "total_recoveries": 0,
      "total_deaths": 0
    },
    "2/23/20": {
      "new_daily_cases": 0,
      "new_daily_deaths": 0,
      "total_cases": 15,
      "total_recoveries": 5,
      "total_deaths": 0
    },
    "2/25/20": {
      "new_daily_cases": 0,
      "new_daily_deaths": 0,
      "total_cases": 51,
      "total_recoveries": 6,
      "total_deaths": 0
    },
    "stat": "ok"
  }]
};

const timelineitems = data.timelineitems;

const datos = timelineitems && timelineitems[0];

const totalCases = Object.values(datos).map(item => item.total_cases);

console.log(totalCases);
```

**P.S.** Beware of the `undefined` in the resul array.

You can easily filter it out with the following code:

```
totalCases.filter(cases => cases !== undefined)
```